# How to change the position of Expand / Collapse button in Tree View in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

I have a tree view in WPF in C# with parent and child nodes. I want to bring the **Expand/Collapse button** to the **right side**. I tried the flow direction property but it is not working as expected.
How to change the position of the Expand/Collapse button in tree view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approch if you override the Treeview Control Template. Here is an example:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

    <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}"
   TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
      Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
      Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <Border Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="1"
            BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="False"
                    CanContentScroll="False"
                    Padding="4">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid Width="15"
                          Height="13"
                          Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="Collapsed">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="Expanded">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Path x:Name="Collapsed"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Margin="1,1,1,1"
                              Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="Expanded"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Margin="1,1,1,1"
                              Data="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"
                              Visibility="Hidden">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0"
                 StrokeThickness="5"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                 Opacity="0" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
   TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
      Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
      Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
      Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
      Value="1,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
      Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            >
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinWidth"
                                    Value="75" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinHeight"
                                    Value="19" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Cold Drinks">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Coke"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Pepsi"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Orange Juice"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Milk"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Iced Tea"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Mango Shake"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Here is the result:[image]